# How to clone images in roboflow?

Tags: roboflow

I'm tring to download images from roboflow universe. The [dataset](https://universe.roboflow.com/linganmin-ecdjx/kitchen-tfer8) didn't release a dataset version, so I got to [Images] tab to clone images to a existed project.

The weird thing happend, there are not showing any projects in my workspace.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA8eK.jpg)

I have read the offical doc, there are some clone images [steps](https://docs.roboflow.com/datasets/adding-data/roboflow-universe#:%7E:text=Clone%20Images%20to%20Your%20Roboflow%20Project):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NKXg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I visited the dataset you linked, clicked clone, and I was able to clone them to my project. Here's a Loom of me doing that: https://www.loom.com/share/85d700f4bc8d42c58dbdadf5f06049e6

If you're unable to clone the images, you could also download the full dataset and then uploading it to your project. Given the dataset is 4,000+ images, it may be easier to use the CLI for upload if your browser uses too much memory for web interface upload. Here's docs on the upload CLI: https://docs.roboflow.com/datasets/adding-data#upload-datasets-with-the-command-line